Is advertising the product of capitalism / Industrial Revolution?
What is the history of advertising? Is it the product of capitalism and the industrial revolution? What is a canonical source on the history of advertising?

According to James Playsted Wood, The Story of Advertising p. 26, the oldest recorded advertisement (3,000 years old),

discovered by an archeologist delving in the ruins of Thebes, has been held up as the first known written advertisement. Inscribed on papyrus, it read: The man-slave, Shem, having run away from his good master, Hapu the Weaver, all good citizens of Thebes are enjoined to help return him. He is a Hittite, 5’ 2” tall, of ruddy complexion and brown eyes. For news of his whereabouts half a gold coin is offered. And for his return to the shop of Hapu the Weaver, where the best cloth is woven to your desires, a whole gold coin is offered.

So advertising predates capitalism by at least few millennia. The book I got this tidbit from is a nice source for history of advertising.
